# Ubuntu 20.04 stop/start/reload network stack with netplan

Tags: networking, netplan

I have looked at all the solutions about how to stop/start/reload the network stack when using netplan configurations (without installing NetworkManager or nmcli) and none of them seem to give a complete option of how to restart the network stack.

I tried:

> sudo systemctl stop networking; sudo systemctl start networking
> sudo systemctl restart networking

> sudo systemctl restart sytemd-networking

> sudo ifdown ; sudo ifup interface

and obviously

> sudo netplan apply

I'm looking for a method that essentially will turn off all the networking and start everything from scratch - as if it were a reboot but without having to reboot. This is especially critical when VLANs are defined since none of the methods that I have tried know how to remove a VLAN definition even if it not longer appears in the /etc/netplan/*.yaml files.

Here is an example netplan file that I was using (this one doesn't include a VLAN though but happened with this file as well):

```
$ cat /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml
  network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
          enp226s0:
                  dhcp4: no
                  addresses: [192.168.10.32/24]
                  gateway4: 192.168.10.254
                  nameservers:
                          addresses: [192.168.1.11]
                          search: [road2.local]
          enp225s0f0:
                 dhcp4: no
                 mtu: 9000
          enp225s0f1:
                 dhcp4: no
                 mtu: 9000
  bonds:
          bond0:
                 dhcp4: no
                 mtu: 9000
                 interfaces:
                           - enp225s0f0
                           - enp225s0f1
                 parameters:
                           mode: balance-rr
                           mii-monitor-interval: 100
  bridges:
          br0:
                 dhcp4: no
                 mtu: 9000
                 interfaces:
                           - bond0
                 addresses: [192.168.1.10/24]
                 gateway4: 192.168.1.254
                 routes:
                           - to: 192.168.9.0/24
                             via: 192.168.1.254
```

Comment: You should [edit] your question and add links to "all the solutions" you looked at and show the "methods you have tried".

Comment: Your question should show the `renderer:` line of your Netplan YAML.